# matching a pattern and replaceing

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace h:mm:ss format held within  tag in my xml file with format "h hours, mm minutes, ss seconds". The problem I am facing is the regex is good to replace if the time tag starts and ends withing a line. I am unable to replace the format when the tag starts and ends at second line.

here is what i am trying -

```
while(<$rd>) {
   my $currLine = $_;
   $_ =~ s/\<time\> *(.):(..):(..) *\<\/time>/$1 hours, $2 minutes, $3 seconds/g;
   print FILE $_;
}
```

My input file looks like this -

```
<time> 1:04:55    </time> this is a good time <time> 
2:04:22 </time> to ask your question Alfred, 
but did you check time <time> 3:45:32 </time> and <time> 02:03:45 </time>
```

I am able to replace the format "h:mm:ss" to "h hours, mm minutes, ss seconds" but not for 2:04:22 as the tag opens and ends at different line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of reading line by line, read up to a `</time>`, and allow for other whitespace than ' ':

```
{
    use autodie 'open';
    open my $input, '<', 'input.xml';
    open my $output, '>', 'output.xml';
    local $/ = '</time>';
    while (<$input>) {
        s/<time>\s*(.):(..):(..)\s*<\/time>/$1 hours, $2 minutes, $3 seconds/;
        print $output $_;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont you need the multiline regex feature? Here is the code snippet I have tried with

```
my $str = '<time> 1:04:55    </time> this is a good time <time>
2:04:22 </time> to ask your question Alfred,
but did you check time <time> 3:45:32 </time> and <time> 02:03:45 </time>';

$str =~ /<time>[\n\s]*(\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)[\n\s]*<\/time>/mg;
print $1, "\n";
print $2, "\n";
print $3, "\n";
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1
04
55
```

Here `/m` tells the regex engine to consider the `$str` as multiline string. And using `g` would apply the changes in all places in the string.

I didnt write the exact solution you need rather just the way multiline regex works. Let me know if you need more help.

### EDIT

I think its worth to note in this question about a multiline regex too.

```
 my $str = '<time> 1:04:55    </time> this is a good time <time>
     2:04:22 </time> to ask your question Alfred,
     but did you check time <time> 3:45:32 </time> and <time> 02:03:45 </time>';

$str =~ s/<time>[\n\s]*(\d?\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)[\n\s]*<\/time>/$1 hours, $2 minutes, $3 seconds/mg;
print $str;
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1 hours, 04 minutes, 55 seconds this is a good time 2 hours, 04 minutes, 22 seconds to ask your question Alfred,
but did you check time 3 hours, 45 minutes, 32 seconds and 02 hours, 03 minutes, 45 seconds
```

The thing is your complete input should be in the string that you are applying the regular expression on.

Comment: Were you using the regex line inside the while loop? This approach requires you to read the whole input in a string and then apply the regex on that. And the change will be applied on the whole string. However, probabl in your case its better to go with the approach mentioned by ysth. However, I will add a bit more specific example in my answer so that no one else get confused.